# парсинг значения биткоин транзакции

Tags: php, api, bitcoin

Подскажите, как мне спарсить значение транзакции по введенном хэшу
например я вытаскиваю с этого адреса транзакции этого хэша
`https://blockchain.info/rawtx/53be3ee60ac19d7c6f52c0872fa5d97b887cbc52a399fb4fc55d12189c97bb81`

Получаю вот такую json строку, как получить с `inputs` значение `addr` и c `out` значение `addr` и `value`, чтобы сравнить эти кошельки с моими значениям (value)

```
{
   "ver":1,
   "inputs":[
      {
         "sequence":4294967295,
         "witness":"",
         "prev_out":{
            "spent":true,
            "tx_index":236490013,
            "type":0,
            "addr":"136YyhcXvAdbSoTSneSWQU8friT4e39gSn",
            "value":6280000,
            "n":0,
            "script":"76a91416fd066170cc66c80fc73138bdb5cd504fa4a84b88ac"
         },
         "script":"483045022100c21a977275b819804da8970efbf0f7c3d13c4828a3b6323e618809b93caf26f5022028820f32a593337518e19743188922f389dcd531fab9a6a1d840f7ad44684bc701210241915ce68a1b0fbc5433874e94409c31ab25d97e8c2b76b8d61b936b03fc0286"
      }
   ],
   "weight":904,
   "block_height":459285,
   "relayed_by":"127.0.0.1",
   "out":[
      {
         "spent":true,
         "tx_index":236489210,
         "type":0,
         "addr":"16oAUtZRXThzsfvXhWJzdymyjYm42rqF6g",
         "value":1252880,
         "n":0,
         "script":"76a9143f93ad68323eb01b2c2c9f9e0ce3f2b13fd9808288ac"
      },
      {
         "spent":true,
         "tx_index":236489210,
         "type":0,
         "addr":"1J52HNDBeazc8PpCmW3XRjBy9GBNSGTXrc",
         "value":5000000,
         "n":1,
         "script":"76a914bb3cdf5a3af9e303de3d6bde30379ea04788fc3a88ac"
      }
   ],
   "lock_time":0,
   "size":226,
   "double_spend":false,
   "time":1490682746,
   "tx_index":236489210,
   "vin_sz":1,
   "hash":"53be3ee60ac19d7c6f52c0872fa5d97b887cbc52a399fb4fc55d12189c97bb81",
   "vout_sz":2
}
```

Comment: Не понятно, что вам в итоге нужно. Адреса ведь указаны в этом json, их и сравнивайте. Количество не можете получить?

Comment: да, количество и как мне их вытащить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Парсите json. `value` указаны в сатоши. 1 биткоин = 100,000,000 сатоши. На примере вашей транзакции:

- с адреса (раздел `inputs`) `136YyhcXvAdbSoTSneSWQU8friT4e39gSn` ушло `6280000 / 100000000 = 0.0628 BTC`
- на адрес (раздел `out`) `16oAUtZRXThzsfvXhWJzdymyjYm42rqF6g` пришло `1252880 / 100000000 = 0.0125288 BTC`
- на адрес (раздел `out`) `1J52HNDBeazc8PpCmW3XRjBy9GBNSGTXrc` пришло `5000000 / 100000000 = 0.05 BTC`